# Flutter GETX state control

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Is it possible to update the state with GETX in the below situation?

I have 3 pages;

1. Portfolio page
2. Details page
3. Edit page

in **Portfolio page** I get data from api and send data by argument to **Details page** when user click portfolio item

```
Get.toNamed(
  Routes.detailsPage,
  arguments: {
    "item":
    controller.item,
  },
);
```

After data passes to **Edit Page** also by argument

```
Get.toNamed(
  Routes.editPage,
  arguments: {
    "item":
    controller.item,
  },
);
```

Than the user edits and saves the data, it will return to the **Details Page** , but new data is not fetched from API and not updated.

Is it possible to update **Details page** state with new data in such situation?

Comment: Yes, It is possible to update fetched detail API. Are they the same controller?. You need to call detail API call again after edit success.

Comment: But in this case each page have own controller

Comment: @OtabekOchilov if previous controller were not destroyed, you can call Get.find<DetailPageController>().getDetailApi(); in edit() function at EditPageController

Answer (score 0):

After the user edits and saves the data, before you call the code that returns to the Details Page, you could call the Details Page Controller to refetch the data.

You should register the controller somewhere before enter in Details Page, for example:

```
Get.put(DetailsPageController());
```

Then when you will close the EditPage you should call the refetch method from Details Page Controller, to update the UI.

```
Get.find<DetailsPageController>().getData();
Get.back();
```